# How to run Kubernates on top of ssh enabled docker nodes?

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, setup-deployment

So I have 5 docker containers running (preconfigured) with ssh. “nodes” are in the same Network subnet and can ping each other. What would be the algorithm to setup kubernates or kind on top of such setup?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes has a project called [`kind`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) (Kubernetes IN Docker) for testing or building kubernetes in Docker containers. There's a [quick start guide](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)

Making a container react like a regular node/vm/host to kubernetes is a complex task, docker in docker is only the start of it.  kind supplies the container half of the equation for you and does [multi node](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start#multinode-clusters) setups

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to install Kubernetes. Too many to cover here.
The
[Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) list some. You might also check out [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)
[RKE](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/) is also a pretty easy way to do it if you already have Docker on the nodes.

Comment: There's more complexity to running k8s inside containers than a vanilla install will cover.

Comment: That's why I suggested RKE. It will let you get a cluster up and running on any set of nodes with the docker run-time available. Kind, AFAIK, is for single nodes.